# Aggregation: Grouping based on array element in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I am new to MongoDB, trying to write an aggregation function such that my output for the input should be same as below

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 1,
      "year": 2022
    },
    "childServices": [
       {"service":"MCT Latency", "sli":99.9},
       {"service":"MCT Packet Loss", "sli":99.9}
      ],
    "service": "Network"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 2,
      "year": 2022
    },
    "childServices": [
       {"service":"MCT Latency", "sli":98.9},
       {"service":"MCT Packet Loss", "sli":99.9}
      ]
    "service": "Network",
  }
]
```

Tried with below, but it's not grouping each childService by date.

```
[{
 $unwind: {
  path: '$childServices'
 }
}, {
 $group: {
  _id: {
   month: {
    $month: '$date'
   },
   year: {
    $year: '$date'
   }
  },
  service: {
   $first: '$service'
  },
  childServices: {
   $first: '$childServices.service'
  },
  sli: {
   $avg: '$childServices.availability'
  }
 }
}, {
 $sort: {
  '_id.month': 1,
  '_id.year': 1
 }
}]
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62fc99c00f5b1cb61d5f1072"
  },
  "service": "Network",
  "date": "01/02/2022 00:32:51",
  "childServices": [
    {
      "service": "MCT Latency",
      "availability": 99.9,
    },
    {
      "service": "MCT Packet Loss",
      "availability": 99.9,
    }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62fc99df0f5b1cb61d5f1073"
  },
  "service": "Network",
  "date": "02/02/2022 00:32:51",
  "childServices": [
    {
      "service": "MCT Latency",
      "availability": 98.3,
   },
      "service": "MCT Packet Loss",
      "availability": 99.9,
   }
 }
]
```

Basically, I want to get into the childService > pick each service > group them by month+year and get their monthly avg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the date from a `string` to a date type, before grouping, like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$childServices"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        "$toDate": "$date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: { <---- Here we are grouping the data for each distinct combination of month, year and child service. This needs to be done because we are using $first accumulator
      _id: {
        month: {
          $month: "$date"
        },
        year: {
          $year: "$date"
        },
        service: "$childServices.service"
      },
      service: {
        $first: "$service"
      },
      childServices: {
        $first: "$childServices.service"
      },
      sli: {
        $avg: "$childServices.availability"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": { <-- In this group, we groupBy month and year, and we push the child services record into an array, using $push. This gives us, for every month and year, the average of all distinct childservices
      "_id": {
        month: "$_id.month",
        year: "$_id.year"
      },
      "childServices": {
        "$push": {
          service: "$childServices",
          sli: "$sli"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id.month": 1,
      "_id.year": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/165mqRh8trr).

Comment: Date is already in date type. In Playground, it's not including second childService i.e. MCT Packet Loss. Each month should have an array of all the childServices with their avg for that month.

Updated my question with correct expected output

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems to be working. If possible please add comments in playground about the first group aggregation, so that I can understand it.

Comment: Added the comments in the answer itself